# How to align my button with the layout's background?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I have a button in my app main page and want to align it according to the layout's background.

This is supposed to be the background of my layout
[image]

This is how it looks on my phone
[image]

But when I run the app, the buttons are not properly aligned, I know I can make the button invisible but the problem is of alignment of button over the background.

If I try the other way, and put the background plain without buttons and set background of buttons the lining of my background won't match with that of the button's lining.
Is there any other way to do this?

The xml file of layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PaperGames"
android:background="@drawable/papergames1"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bbollywood"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btictactoe"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
    android:text="BOLLYWOOD" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btictactoe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bbollywood"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
    android:text="TIC TAC TOE" />
```

Comment: i think this is not way to do it man !! you should make a custom buttons and change your background by not showing buttons in it and use your custom buttons like shown in picture because you are trying to make a clickable button which is shown in your background picture but it will never adjust on all screens

Comment: I have mentioned this option in my question, the problem with this is that the lines of my background doesnt match with those of button's background. You can see here http://imgur.com/HwnROH9

Comment: it will never align

Comment: because you have all different screen sizes on every different devices so you have to make your custom layout as shown in picture